# Prevent delete of last div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slight problem in a feature I am trying to implement on a web page. I have two images, a plus and a minus sign, when plus is clicked it clones a div which consists of a few text box's. The minus image is meant to delete this div.

At the moment, I cannot seem to find a way to stop the last div from being deleted when I click on the minus. I want to just prevent the last row from being deleted and using an alert to inform the user that it cannot be deleted.

Can anyone give me some insight to this? I've searched on here for a while and found something similar, but it's all done using JQuery which I have no experience with.

Here is the code I am using to try and delete the div's.

```
  function deleteRow1() {

    // row-to-clone1 is the name of the row that is being cloned
    var div = document.getElementById('row-to-clone1');

    if (div) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }

    if ((div).length != 1) {
        alert("Cannot delete all rows.").remove();
    }
}
```

When I try do delete the row it displays the alert but still deletes the div. I realise this is probably a very easy fix and my implementation of the above may not be correct, if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Make your check before you call the `if (div)`.

Comment: @Press can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Use `if (divs.length > 1) { .. } else { alert('don\'t delete!'); }` instead of two if statements as they will BOTH run regardless of each other's true/false values.

Comment: @Press I've changed it to how you described, but it still doesn't allow me to delete any rows, the alert keeps popping up when I try to delete a row.

Comment: That is because `getElementById` can only get 1 element.

Comment: Ahh, @Press thanks, I've been looking at this for too long. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, so use a class to fetch them

```js
function deleteRow1() {
  // row-to-clone1 is the name of the row that is being cloned
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('row-to-clone1');

  if (divs.length > 1) {
    divs[0].parentNode.removeChild(divs[0]);
  } else {
    alert("Cannot delete all rows.")
  }
}

function add1() {
  var div = document.getElementById('row-to-clone1');
  if (div) {
    var clone = div.cloneNode(true);
    delete clone.id;
    div.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add1()">Add</button>
<button onclick="deleteRow1()">Delete</button>
<div id="row-to-clone1" class="row-to-clone1">div</div>
```

Comment: in my HTML file, I have the `row-to-clone` as an ID. I tried changing it all to a class but it makes no difference. I implemented your code above but I cannot delete any row now, even though your example runs exactly how I want mine to work.

Comment: @chickensoup can you update [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tgzcuyqm/1/) to recreate your case

Comment: can you see this? My code is below my name commented in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randomposter/p0jL578f/)